# Adding Direction and Distance into attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, distance, direction, bearing

I just want to add direction (Bearing: i.e N 25 35 E) and Distance (Length: 125 meters) as my new field in polyline/line data.

Is there a Plugin to generate these fields?

I tried to used `Export/Add geometry columns` in my line data, but only `"Length"` value was added.

Comment: So far I can use the mmqgis plugin to give me distance. Am exploring the direction problem.

Comment: What does your polyline data look like? Distance is relatively easy to calculate - however, 'bearing' may change over the length of a polyline. Are you looking for bearing from **start point** to **endpoint**?

Comment: Yes, im looking for bearing from start point to end point... thanks

Comment: Do you want straight-line distance from startpoint to endpoint, or length of line following the path of the line?  These could vary widely if the line segment has intermediate curves or other changes of direction.

Answer (score 44):

You can calculate bearing in the Field Calculator in QGIS. This works in UTM (metric) coordinates over small distances (hundreds of km), but something more sophisticated would be needed for large distances or for decimal degrees.

Open the attribute table for your line layer, toggle editing, and click the Field Calculator button to open the dialog:

[image]

Create a new field as decimal with 1 or 2 precision.

Paste this code into the "Expression" box, and click "OK": `(atan((xat(-1)-xat(0))/(yat(-1)-yat(0)))) * 180/3.14159 + (180 *(((yat(-1)-yat(0)) < 0) + (((xat(-1)-xat(0)) < 0 AND (yat(-1) - yat(0)) >0)*2)))`

The first part calculates the inverse tangent of the x and y differences and converts it to degrees (180/pi). The second part adds either 180 or 360 to the resulting figure to give a bearing from 0-360°.

*Edit - updated formula as per suggestion*

```
CASE
   WHEN ((yat(-1)-yat(0)) = 0 and (xat(-1) - xat(0)) >0) THEN 90
   WHEN ((yat(-1)-yat(0)) = 0 and (xat(-1) - xat(0)) <0) THEN 270
   ELSE (atan((xat(-1)-xat(0))/(yat(-1)-yat(0)))) * 180/pi() + 
       (180 * (((yat(-1)-yat(0)) < 0) + (((xat(-1)-xat(0)) < 0 AND (yat(-1) - yat(0)) > 0)*2)))
END
```

Comment: A most elegant solution, thanks. I'd mention that if you need to determine the bearing for each segment of a polyline you can do this by splitting the line shapefile with the 'Split Feature' plug-in. Then load the new (split) shapefile and follow the above procedure.

Comment: @arzandia - note that you MUST be using **QGIS 1.9** (see the home page for beta downloads) as the xat() and yat() functions don't work in 1.7, which you are using!

Comment: i already used the plug in you have mentioned. as you can see the image, the layer's name is "splitted"...

Comment: @nhopton - i appreciate the comment re split feature, I needed that!

Comment: I think the questioner(?) should mark this as the answer.

Comment: Is there anyway to substitute different x/y values in this equation?  I assume these x/y values are based off of how the line was drawn (i.e. left to right).  However if I have lines that were drawn between two points and a bearing calculated this way, it would not show correct direction of flow of water if in fact the line should have been drawn in the opposite manner. Can I substitute the correct x/y values based off of known direction of flow?

Comment: @cbunn - the `yat(0)` and `yat(-1)` values are the y values of beginning and end of line, respectively (any negative index gives the end point) - to calculate reverse bearing, just swap the index values.

Comment: So if I had a field for the actual start/end points could I insert it in place of yat(0) and yat(-1) and xat(0) and xat(-1)?

Comment: To answer my own question, "Yes you can insert field values for yat(0)/yat(-1) and xat(0)/xat(-1)."

Comment: For me I had to do some changes to the script to get it to work: (atan((xat(0)-xat(1))/(yat(0)-yat(1)))) * 180/3.14159 + (180 *(((yat(0)-yat(1)) < 0) + (((xat(0)-xat(1)) < 0 AND (yat(0) - yat(1)) >0)*2)))

Comment: @Oskar, your modification will give the bearing from the second (1) to the first (0) node in the line, NOT from the first to the last (-1)!

Comment: Aha, sorry! For some reason the method from the last didn't work, therefore I used first and second for my project.

Comment: Hi, did you try this in newer QGIS - 2.18 or 3.x? Because I am still getting NULL output for all these expressions from here despite separate parts like "yat(0)" etc. give me correct output. Layer is in UTM.

Comment: @Juhele works in QGIS 3.10-3.16

Answer (score 24):

You do not need a plugin. Everything is in the class QgsPoint of PyQGIS

If you examine the contents of a QGIS point class with the Python built-in function dir() in the Python Console.

```
dir(point])
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__'
, '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', 
'__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', 
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'azimuth', 
'multiply', 'set', 'setX', 'setY', 'sqrDist', 'sqrDistToSegment', 'toDegreesMinutesSeconds', 'toString', 'wellKnownText', 'x', 'y']
```

You can see there are **azimuth** and **sqrDist** functions and after a few tries:

```
- xy[0].azimuth(xy[1]) or xy[1].azimuth(xy[0]) gives the azimuth direction between two points(in degrees, +/- 180°)
- xy[0].sqrDist(xy[1]) give the square distance between two points (in the unit of the project)
```

The problem
[image]

So in the Python console

```
def select_all(layer):
     layer.select([])
     layer.setSelectedFeatures([obj.id() for obj in layer])

myline = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
select_all(myline)
for elem in myline.selectedFeatures():
      xy = elem.geometry().asPolyline()
```

now xy contains all the nodes (points) of the line

```
# first point
print "x=%2d y=%2d" % (xy[0].x(),xy[0].y())
x=112935 y=117784
# and others...
```

Using all node points of the line:

1) azimuth point i to point i + 1 (+/- 180°) (nodes of a line)

```
for i in range(len(xy)-1):
     print "x=%2d y=%2d azim=%6.1f azim2=%6.1f" % (xy[i].x(), xy[i].y(), xy[i].azimuth(xy[i+1]), xy[i+1].azimuth(xy[i]))

x=112935 y=117784 azim= 168.4 azim2= -11.6
x=113032 y=117312 azim=-167.5 azim2=  12.5
x=112926 y=116835 azim= 177.3 azim2=  -2.7
x=112943 y=116472 azim= 145.1 azim2= -34.9
[...]
```

2) euclidean distance between point i and point i + 1

```
for i in range(len(xy)-1):
     print "x=%2d y=%2d dist=%6.1f" % (xy[i].x(), xy[i].y(), xy[i].sqrDist(xy[i+1]))

x=112935 y=117784 dist=232533.9
x=113032 y=117311 dist=238243.6
x=112926 y=116835 dist=131839.8
x=112943 y=116472 dist=209268.1
[...]
```

After, it is not very difficult to add these values to the attribute table.

I use this technique to analyze the lineaments (geology) with matplotlib and the Script Runner plugin

[image]

Comment: +1 - Nice solution! Must ... learn ... Python ...

Comment: This is a great solution and super valuable for geologists.. but also sooo complicated

Answer (score 13):

The solution provided by @Simbamangu is pretty effective but not cover all cases. For example,applying the formula with an horizontal displacament will NULL the result, so you must use this formulate in Field Calculator of QGIS

```sql
case
   when yat(-1)-yat(0) < 0 or yat(-1)-yat(0) > 0
       then (atan((xat(-1)-xat(0))/(yat(-1)-yat(0)))) * 180/3.14159 + 
       (180 * (((yat(-1)-yat(0)) < 0) + (((xat(-1)-xat(0)) < 0 AND (yat(-1) - yat(0)) > 0)*2)))
   when ((yat(-1)-yat(0)) = 0 and (xat(-1) - xat(0)) >0) then 90
   when ((yat(-1)-yat(0)) = 0 and (xat(-1) - xat(0)) <0) then 270
end
```

Comment: is it possible to do this in postgis? The postGIS command called ST_Azimuth only works on points, and I have not been able to find any examples of this same process in postgresql, postgis.