# Calculating point angle in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, angles, bearing

I was wondering if there is a plugin, or a field calculation in QGIS to calculate a points rotation angle. ETGeoWizards has a tool that allows you to calculate a point layer rotation angle from a source line layer. Does anyone know of a similar process within QGIS?

Comment: What is that? An angle to rotate the point layer so it best matches (overlaps) the line one?

Comment: Yes and No.  Its to know the cardinal direction of a point, in reference to a line.  For example, the angle a house faces a street.  Is the house facing 75 degrees north?

Comment: But a house is not a point, you usually have a clear edge or face (2d) to construct an angle and compare to. With just a line and a point, you can get any angle you want from out of them. You need another anchoring point or some other constraint. Is this the angle of the line of minimal distance between the two?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this.  This process is for 3D modeling, so it is taken care of a different way.

Comment: Points in GIS have no orientation. Unless you were to go and specify one as an attribute.  What you want is the angle of the line, perpindicular to a point. Same method as noted in my answer below, me thinks.

Comment: That is right Willy, but I didn't see in your post how to get the angle from the line to the appropriate point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend these :

- [Adding Direction and Distance into Attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24260/adding-direction-and-distance-into-attribute-table)
- http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Vector_intersection_-_angles

Comment: Thank you, but these are for line segments.  I am looking for a point, with reference to a line.

Answer (score 1):

This article can help you!
[Rotating point layer according to line layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428385/rotating-point-layer-according-to-line-layer-in-qgis)
Use geometry by expression in QGIS and the function that the article mentions.