# Rotating point layer according to line layer in QGIS part 2

Tags: qgis, expression, rotate, qgis-expression

Related to the question line below. How do I make the arrow point to the line correctly ?

This code did not work :

```
with_variable('myvalue',line_interpolate_angle(geometry:=intersection(buffer(geometry:=$geometry, distance:=50, segments:=3),overlay_nearest(layer:='railways', expression:=$geometry)[0]), distance:=50),if(@myvalue < 180,@myvalue+90,@myvalue-90))
```

[Rotating point layer according to line layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428385/rotating-point-layer-according-to-line-layer-in-qgis)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the rotation of the arrow marker, use this expression on the point layer and replace `line` in line 4 with the name of the line layer.

*Explanation: for each point, calculate the azimuth (angle) with the function [azimuth()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#azimuth) from the initial point (`$geometry`) to the closest point on the line (to get the line: use [overlay_nearest()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-nearest)) with the function [closest_point()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#closest-point). Convert radians to degrees with [degrees()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#degrees).*

```
degrees(
    azimuth(
        $geometry,
        closest_point( overlay_nearest ( 'line', $geometry)[0],
        $geometry
        )
    )
)
```

*Dotted line for visualization purpose only:*
[image]