# Create line-type symbology perpendicular to a segment in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, markers, geometry-generator, angles

I want to create a symbology (line type) for a point layer in QGIS. This line must be perpendicular to the segments of a polygon. I attach an image:
[image]

To do this I entered an expression in the rotation section of the symbol
[image]
The expression is this:

```
degrees(
    azimuth(
        $geometry,
        closest_point(
            aggregate(
                'lotto',
                'collect',
                $geometry,
                intersects($geometry, $geometry)
            ),
            $geometry
        )
    )
)
```

However the symbology of points 1, 2, 6, 7 is correct, while that of points 3, 4, 5 is not, as the calculated rotation value is 0.

How can I also make points 3, 4, 5 perpendicular to the various segments? is it possible by modifying this expression or do I have to use another approach.

The layers in question are two different, a point layer and a polygonal one.

Comment: Maybe you can use something similar to: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428385/rotating-point-layer-according-to-line-layer-in-qgis/428391#428391

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach works for points outside the polygon. However, points inside the polygon are already the closest point to themselves, so the azimuth returns 0.

Try converting the polygon to a line.

Wrapping the inner $geometry in an exterior_ring seems to work (on a small sample size!):

```
degrees(
    azimuth(
        $geometry,
        closest_point(
            aggregate(
                'lotto',
                'collect',
                exterior_ring($geometry)
            ),
            $geometry
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you convert your `polygons to lines`, `split the lines at each vertex`, calculate the `azimuth` of each line using the field calculator, add 90 to the azimuth and then `join` the modified azimuth attribute to your points. Then you can control the rotation of the points via data defined override using the joined attribute.