# Calculating line direction in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, line

I have a large file of a road network. I need to calculate the value of direction (in degrees or radians) of the line segments, and save this value to a new field. I need to use MapInfo.

I have found this excellent example using qgis, but need to undertake the work using MapInfo. Does anyone have a solution. I tried the basic idea of using the function listed in the solution and copy and pasting that in, but it does not work.

[How to add Direction and Distance to attribute table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24260/how-to-add-direction-and-distance-to-attribute-table)

Hope this all makes sense. To conclude, I need to calculate direction for each line segment and add them to a new field in MapInfo.

Comment: in Mapinfo or using Mapinfo files? see http://mikeongis.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/calculate-road-direction-in-mapinfo-files/

Comment: in Mapinfo using mid/mif files @Mapperz
thanks!