# Distance-direction computation of lines with exactly/more than two nodes?

Tags: qgis, distance, direction

A distance and direction tutorial provided as an Answer at 
**[How to add Direction and Distance to attribute table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24260/how-to-add-direction-and-distance-to-attribute-table)** uses:

1. *xat (0 ), xat (-1 ) and yat (0 ), yat (-1)* for **start and end points of lines**; in addition to
2. (*atan((xat(-1)-xat(0))/(yat(-1)-yat(0)))) * 180/3.14159 + (180 *(((yat(-1)-yat(0)) < 0) + (((xat(-1)-xat(0)) < 0 AND (yat(-1) - yat(0)) >0)*2)))* to **calculate direction**

I would like to know any difference in application if lines with more than 1 part and/or nodes are used.

Would there be any difference between using lines with 2 nodes vs lines with more than 2 nodes and segments?

Which assumptions would QGIS automatically use/make in the following scenarios below:

a -  regarding **direction**: the overall direction is derived from the difference in start and end node **OR** would it be the average of each individual computed segment.

b - regarding **distance**: is it the distance between start node and end node **OR** is it the sum total of each segment that is represented in the distance

Comment: @PolyGeo or VeM: I want to upvote this question but find the code a mess. Can you tidy it? Is it even necessary? Thanks.

Comment: @martinf I have just tried to but it is not within my area of expertise so those efforts may be somewhat superficial compared to what you were thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) Direction is calculated from the difference between start and end point

B) Distance of line is best to be calculated simpy by `$length` and is the sum of all individual parts

Also note nhopton's comment on how to get bearing of each individual segment:

> A most elegant solution, thanks. I'd mention that if you need to
>   determine the bearing for each segment of a polyline you can do this
>   by splitting the line shapefile with the 'Split Feature' plug-in. Then
>   load the new (split) shapefile and follow the above procedure.

**EDIT**

Distance `as crow flies` is calculated as:

```
sqrt( (xat(0) - xat(-1))^2 + (yat(0) - yat(-1))^2 )
```

Comment: Thank you to you both! But just one more query then regarding the distance in the direction-distance tutorial above. would the distance value be the $length (i.e. sum of individual parts) or the distance, as the crow flies between start and end node.

Comment: I don't know, which distance you mean? The formula you gave calculates angle, not distance, and distance calculated by `$length` is sum of parts. I edited my answer to include formula for distance calculated "as crow flies"

Comment: The formula for as crow flies is perfect! Thank you!