# Creating atlas along line/route using QGIS

Tags: qgis, atlas, map-book, strip-map

I'd like to create a mapbook along a given route that is designated by a single linear feature.

Is it possible to have QGIS (2.2) automatically compose a series of pdfs that overlap by a given percent and rotate the map to optimize space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer in not 100 % correct or possible to follow. Unfortunately I don't have the answer. The problem is that your PDF has two main restrictions: rotation and scale. The rotation is more or less easy but the problem (for me) is that I didn't find a way to automatically fix the scale of the grid with the number of segments that we have to obtain for the grid.  I tried to do the same as you but:

The only way that I found to obtain a grid was to use: v.split.length several times till have the linear feature with an approximative number of sections that fix with my scale. 
Then, in every segment generated you have to obtain the direction (([How to add Direction and Distance to attribute table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24260/how-to-add-direction-and-distance-to-attribute-table/24430#24430)) (atan((xat(-1)-xat(0))/(yat(-1)-yat(0)))) * 180/3.14159 + (180 *(((yat(-1)-yat(0)) < 0) + (((xat(-1)-xat(0)) < 0 AND (yat(-1) - yat(0)) >0)*2))))

I posted my question here: [Creating atlas along line/route in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168087/problems-creating-an-atlas-along-line-route-in-qgis)

Answer (score 2):

QGIS' Composer has the ability to create an "Atlas" built in, and it works very well.

Assuming you have a single feature defining your route, you'll need to create a 'grid' representing how you want the pages rotated and sized to use as the "Coverage Layer"

If your route is actually distinct features, you can just use the route layer as the "Coverage Layer" to define the pages.

Steps are basically as follows:

- Create a new composer window
- Add a new map item
- Click "Atlas Generation" in the right pane
- Check "Generate an Atlas"
- Choose your coverage layer (as above - either a grid you create, or your line layer if it is multiple features
- fill in any of the remaining (mostly optional) settings

Pages will rotate automatically to match the alignment of the feature in the Coverage Layer, and you can specify the Margin around each feature on the Maps "Item Properties" pane by Selecting "Controlled By Atlas" and entering a percentage.