# How to measure angle in QGIS

Tags: qgis, angles

While measuring an angle in QGIS using measure angle tool, it is showing as 0 to 180 degree for clockwise direction and -1 to -179 for anticlockwise. What I need is, interior angle between vertices of irregular polygon. How should I calculate in QGIS?

Comment: Do you want to populate an attribute with the value or use the value for further processing? GUI or python based solution? There a several recent Q&A on calculation of angles given 3 points.

Comment: Yes, I wanna populate using some tools in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

http://anitagraser.com/2015/05/24/how-to-create-illuminated-contours-tanaka-style/ contains some way to do this:

First you split the lines/polygons into their atomic segments with v.split.

Then you calculate the azimuth for each of those features, see eg [How to add Direction and Distance to attribute table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24260/how-to-add-direction-and-distance-to-attribute-table) for the formula.

I don't know a better way but maybe there is.

Comment: I have tried to find angle in this way. But what am getting is only true bearing (i.e., an angle of line from true north). I wanna know interior angles of polygon.

Comment: Oh, I misread that, sorry! That sounds like a job for python scripting. Out of my league at the moment.